# Help me identify book where main character enters virtual fantasy world

Tags: story-identification

I'd like help identifying a book about a teenage girl that goes to an arcade, and they have a virtual reality console that they hook you up to.

She goes back in time to a fantasy setting, but the equipment is damaged and she can't leave.  She dies repeatedly but can't get out until she beats it.

It had a green cover, I think.
That's all I remember.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it, or if it was geared towards any particular age group?

Comment: I see you have been answered, but if you like that premise check out "Discordia: The Eleventh Dimension".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Heir Apparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_Apparent_(novel))" by Vivian Vande Velde

> Heir Apparent is a science fiction/fantasy novel by young-adult
>   fiction author Vivian Vande Velde, about a girl who becomes trapped
>   inside a looping virtual reality role-playing game called Heir
>   Apparent.
>
> *"Heir Apparent was a lot of fun to write because it's about a girl caught in a virtual-reality-type game. Even though Giannine finds
>   herself in a vaguely medieval world, I didn't have to worry about
>   historical accuracy. I also was able to keep throwing all sorts of
>   things at her -- a dragon, an army of ghosts, and a
>   poetry-loving/head-chopping statue."*

[image]

Comment: Note green cover

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much!  I love this book and look forward to reading it again.